# No. of equilateral triangles required to completely fill a bigger equilateral triangle

Tags: triangles

$\triangle ABC$ is equilateral with side length=2.1cm

Smaller equilateral triangles with side length=1cm are placed over $\triangle ABC$ so that it is fully covered. Find the minimum number of such small triangles.

I am not getting it. How is it possible to completely fill with such dimensions?

Comment: triangles my overlap.

Comment: @ Hagen von Eitzen that might be the case. Since I am unable to get it without overlapping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not answer to the question.

I just post a rough sketch showing a way of how the 6 equilateral triangles can be arranged to cover the original.[image]

Answer (score 2):

Six triangle suffice (three in the corners and three in the middle of the sides).
It is not possible with less than six triangles:
Let $D$ be the midpoint of $AB$, $E$ the midpoint of $BC$, $F$ the midpoint of $CA$.
Then the distance between any two of the points $A,B,C,D,E,F$ is $\ge1.05>1$, hence no two of them can be covered by the same side-1-triangle.